# CSS Dropdown Same Width

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("primaryNavigation");
    if (x.className === "show") {
        x.className = "hide";
    } else {
        x.className = "show";
    }
}
```

```css
/* NAVIGATION - MENU */

nav {
    background-color: #0000ff;
}

nav button {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: .5rem;
    right: 2%;
}

nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

nav ul.show {
    display: flex;
}

nav ul.hide {
    display: none;
}

nav ul li {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: 450;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

nav ul li.active a {
    background-color: #f52c39;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #4c9bff;
}

.clearfix:after,
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
/* DROP DOWN MENU */

ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background-color: #0000ff;
}

li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    background-color: #0000ff;
}

nav ul ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #4c9bff;
}
```

```html
<nav class="clearfix">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</button>
    <ul class="hide" id="primaryNavigation">
        <li class="active"><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="adventures.php">Adventures</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="whiteWater.php">White Water Rafting</a></li>
                <li><a href="hikingZipline.php">Hiking &amp; Zipline</a></li>
                <li><a href="camping.php">Camping</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="guides.php">Guides</a></li>
        <li><a href="booking.php">Booking</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I want my dropdown menu to be the same width as the parent. (FYI: It is responsive and changes into a hamburger). I realize this is probably so easy for someone (but I'm just learning). I've tried all the solutions I've seen listed here and other place to no avail. THANK YOU for any help.

Comment: and your `myFunction()`??

Comment: I added the JS Function above. Thanks

Comment: you want that submenu come above that main menu or that main menu side by side?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, I want the submenu to be the same width as the menu item it is dropped down from. Let's say "Adventures" (the parent) is 30px wide, I want the dropdown to be the same width, rather than 20px (I'm just guessing width).

Comment: then it will overlap on rest , do you want your menu as on snippet?

Comment: Durga, I don't even know enough to know what "as on snippet"? means. Here is a link to my test home page where you can see how Adventures dropdown is not the same width and when it changes to ipad viewport, it is larger that the parent. When it becomes a hamburger, all it good. file:///C:/Users/Tanja%20Crouch/Documents/1%20Spring%202017/CIT%20230/cit230/salmonriver/indexTest.html